# App is crashing on accessing contacts book of iPhone

Tags: ios

When I am tapping contacts to access contacts of iPhone,my app crashed. I have used following code.

```
-(NSString*)readContactBook{

    @try {
        NSString *jsonResponse;

        NSLog(@"Read Addressbook: %@", [self getTimeInMilliSeconds]);

        CFErrorRef *error = nil;

        ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);

        __block BOOL accessGranted = NO;
        if (ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion != NULL) { // we're on iOS 6
            dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
            ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
                accessGranted = granted;
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
            });
            dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

        }
        else { // we're on iOS 5 or older
            accessGranted = YES;
        }

        if (accessGranted) {

            NSLog(@"Fetching Contacts from AB");
            ABRecordRef source = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBook);
            CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBook, source, kABPersonSortByFirstName);

            CFIndex nPeople = CFArrayGetCount(allPeople);

            //CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

            NSMutableArray* arrContacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

            NSLog(@"Total Contacts in device: %ld",nPeople);

            for (int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++)
            {
                ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);

                //get First Name and Last Name
                NSMutableArray *arrAllContacts = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]init] autorelease];

                NSString *strFirstName = (__bridge NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

                NSString *strLastName =  (__bridge NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);


                if (!strFirstName) {
                    strFirstName = @"";
                }
                if (!strLastName) {
                    strLastName = @"";
                }


                //get Phone Numbers

                NSMutableArray *phoneNumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                ABMultiValueRef multiPhones = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
                for(CFIndex i=0;i<ABMultiValueGetCount(multiPhones);i++) {
                    NSMutableDictionary *dictContact = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init] autorelease];

                    CFStringRef phoneNumberRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiPhones, i);
                    CFStringRef locLabel = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(multiPhones, i);
                    NSString *phoneLabel =(__bridge NSString*) ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(locLabel);
                    if([phoneLabel isEqualToString:@""] || !phoneLabel) {
                        phoneLabel = @"phone";
                    }
                    NSString *phoneNumber = (__bridge NSString *) phoneNumberRef;
                    [phoneNumbers addObject:phoneNumber];

                    [dictContact setObject:phoneNumber forKey:phoneLabel];


                     CFRelease(phoneNumberRef);
                    CFRelease(locLabel);
```

In one case when I commented  `CFRelease(phoneNumberRef);CFRelease(locLabel);` app stopped crashing when it access contacts.but issue reopened after 2 months.
Kindly suggest appropriate fix.

Comment: What error shows in the debugger ?

Comment: check once you are get the values are empty or not

Comment: First of all Add all exception break point and then it will show you error atleast where it is crashing